# Need to get current location of uiprogressview tint in pixels

Tags: ios, xcode

So I need to know the length in pixels of the tint of my uiprogressview so I can draw at this location. Any ideas how to get this information?

Comment: this question is unclear, provide more info.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the math logic like this

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(progressview.frame);
CGFloat length = width * progressview.progress;
```